# Video is not playing repeating iOS. Show this log

Tags: ios, objective-c, video-streaming, mpmovieplayercontroller

When I load the Video url in `MPMovieplayercontroller` in `Similator`
the log is printing like this what can I do now.

```
_itemFailedToPlayToEnd: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 2;
    old = 0;
}
```

So, that the Video is not Viewing in my player

help me..

Answer (score 1):

There could be some problems with your url...

1. Your url could have spaces. Fill the spaces - stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding.
2. Try changing the source type of the player this might help.
   movieplayer. movieSourceType = // source type.

Try running app on a device also sometimes might be the problem due to simulator.
First try on real device if it doesnot work try the above 2 suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Just a word of warning since I battled this problem for 2 hours and it turned out to be something really simple and quite surprising.

MPMoviePlayerViewController in iOS7 **cannot play mov files**. In iOS8, however, it works fine.